# Rascal function with abstract pattern as formal parameter

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to do this:

```
data A = a(str s);
void show(A a(str s)) = println(s);
A x = a("hi");
show(x);
```

but I get this error:

```
|prompt:///|(0,7,<1,0>,<1,7>): The called signature: show(A),
does not match the declared signature:  void show(node);
```

Is this because this is currently broken (as the tutor page for TypeConstrained abstract patterns suggests), or am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
void show(a(str s)) = println(s);
```

where did you see this `A` prefix in the tutor?

Comment: Thanks. I probably made up this `A` prefix myself (mixing up the syntax for function declarations with normal parameters and with pattern parameters).